Mobile connect text join to enroll via landing pages
We sent one sms using join keyword in that sms one land8ng pages link is there.in that landing pages one member and another agent box option is there.if any body click member box.if the phone number what we sent matches then trigger another message.we also need to send all these data to salesforce crm.how is this possible
